# Simplify a equation containing factorial, summation, and fraction

Tags: fractions, factorial

I really need some help on simplifying this math equation. Please help me reduce it as simple as possible! Thanks in advance!

$$\large P_0=\frac{1}{\left[\sum_{i=0}^{M-1} \frac{1}{i!}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\mu}\right)^i\right]+\frac{1}{M!}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\mu}\right)^M\frac{M\mu}{M\mu-\lambda}}$$

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to simplify normalization factor in derivation of [ErlangC formula](http://www.mitan.co.uk/erlang/elgcmath.htm). It can not really be simplified any further, using elemenetary function.

The sum can be summed in terms of incomplete gamma-function $\Gamma_x(s) = \int_{x}^\infty y^{s-1} \mathrm{e}^{-y} \mathrm{d} y$:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{M-1} \frac{1}{i!} \frac{\lambda^i}{\mu^i} = \exp(\frac{\lambda}{\mu}) \frac{\Gamma_{\frac{\lambda}{\mu}}\left(M \right)}{\Gamma(M)}
$$

Comment: I see.. awh, i see integrals.. sigh. Anyways, thank you for the help :) Have a nice day!